# Saving and restoring RadixTree object

Tags: java, performance, android, memory-management, serialization

I have a large word-file which is fixed with over 240 000 words. I need to check if a specific word exists in this list. I thought that it would be a good idea to create a `RadixTree` for this problem.

The text file consists of 240 000 lines, each of which contains one word, which is read into a `String`. Each `string` is then parsed into a `char[]` to access the individual characters, each `char` is then placed into the tree separately.

Android puts a limit of 16-26MB of RAM usage per application if I am correct. When my application runs it consistently hits this mark during the initialization of the large `Vocabulary` object. It takes around 47 seconds to initialize the `Vocabulary` object and about 1/10 of a ms to see if a word exists in this `Vocabulary`. Right now I am afraid that I made a mistake by implementing the `RadixTree` data-structure since it costs too much RAM and takes way too long with 47 seconds...

Would this every be possible to use on a real device? E.g. that the speed would be under 0.5 seconds instead of 47.

**My idea was to load the object to later restore it. However this is even slower, loading an object took about 5x longer. Oh dear.**

### `Vocabulary` Class

```
package nl.mprog.ghost.datastructure;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.Serializable;

import nl.mprog.ghost.enumeration.Language;

public class Vocabulary implements Serializable {
    RadixTree mRadixTree;
    Language mLanguage;

    public Vocabulary(Context context, Language language) {
        this.mLanguage = language;
        mRadixTree = new RadixTree(context, language);
    }

    public boolean isWord(String word) {
        return mRadixTree.isWord(word);
    }
```

### `RadixTree` class

```
package nl.mprog.ghost.datastructure;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import nl.mprog.ghost.R;
import nl.mprog.ghost.enumeration.Language;

public class RadixTree implements Serializable {
    private RadixTreeNode mRoot = new RadixTreeNode();
    private ArrayList<RadixTreeNode> mActiveNodes;

    public RadixTree(Context context, Language language) {
        readInWords(getFileScanner(context, language));
    }

    public void readInWords(Scanner scanner) {
        String word;

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            word = scanner.nextLine();
            mRoot.insertWord(word, mRoot);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }

    public Scanner getFileScanner(Context context, Language language) {
        Scanner scanner;

        switch (language) {
            case DUTCH:
                scanner = new Scanner(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dutch));
                break;
            case ENGLISH:
            scanner = new Scanner(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.english));
            break;
            default:
            scanner = new Scanner(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.english));
            break;
        }

        return scanner;
    }

    public boolean isWord(String word) {
        RadixTreeNode activeNode = mRoot;
        char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            activeNode = activeNode.findNode(activeNode, chars[i]);
            if(activeNode == null) return false;
        }

        if(activeNode.mIsWordEnd) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### `RadixTreeNode` class

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class RadixTreeNode implements Serializable {
    RadixTreeNode[] mChildren = new RadixTreeNode[0];
    char mCharacter = '0';
    boolean mIsWordEnd;

    public RadixTreeNode() {
    }

    public RadixTreeNode(char character) {
        this.mCharacter = character;
    }

    public RadixTreeNode(char character, boolean isWordEnd) {
        this.mCharacter = character;
        this.mIsWordEnd = isWordEnd;
    }

    public void insert(char character) {
        for(RadixTreeNode node : mChildren) {
            if(node.mCharacter == character) {
                return;
            }
        }

        addChild(new RadixTreeNode(character));
    }

    public void insert(char character, boolean isWordEnd) {
        for(RadixTreeNode node : mChildren) {
            if(node.mCharacter == character) {
                return;
            }
        }

        addChild(new RadixTreeNode(character, isWordEnd));
    }

    private void addChild(RadixTreeNode node) {
        if(mChildren.length == 0) {
            mChildren = new RadixTreeNode[1];
            mChildren[0] = node;
        } else {
            RadixTreeNode[] temp = new RadixTreeNode[mChildren.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(mChildren, 0, temp, 0, mChildren.length);
            temp[mChildren.length] = node;
            mChildren = temp;
        }
    }

    public RadixTreeNode[] getChildren() {
        return mChildren;
    }

    public void insertWord(String word, RadixTreeNode root) {
        RadixTreeNode activeNode = root;
        char[] array = word.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < (array.length - 1); i++) {
            activeNode.insert(array[i]);
            activeNode = findNode(activeNode, array[i]);
        }

            activeNode.insert(array[array.length - 1], true);
    }

    public RadixTreeNode findNode(RadixTreeNode startPosition, char character) {
        RadixTreeNode[] children = startPosition.getChildren();
        if(children.length == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for(RadixTreeNode rtn : children) {
                if(rtn.mCharacter == character) return rtn;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276641/way-to-store-a-large-dictionary-with-low-memory-footprint-fast-lookups-on-and) because it involves nearly the same problem and there is a good answer in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Think in terms of interfaces instead of implementations

Use interface types instead of implementations whenever possible.
So instead of this:

> ```
> private ArrayList<RadixTreeNode> mActiveNodes;
> ```

Declare as a `List<RadixTreeNode>` instead:

```
private List<RadixTreeNode> mActiveNodes;
```

However, on closer look it turns out that `mActiveNodes` is unused.
Then it's better to delete it.

#### Use `boolean` values directly

Instead of this:

> ```
>     if(activeNode.mIsWordEnd) {
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         return false;
>     }
> ```

Write simply:

```
    return activeNode.mIsWordEnd;
```

#### Extract repetitive code to an another block when possible

The cases are very repetitive of this `switch`:

> ```
>     switch (language) {
>         case DUTCH:
>             scanner = new Scanner(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dutch));
>             break;
>         case ENGLISH:
>             scanner = new Scanner(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.english));
>             break;
>         default:
>             scanner = new Scanner(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.english));
>             break;
>     }
> ```

It would be better to change the cases to assign to an id the appropriate `R.raw.something` value, and then create the scanner after the switch,
typing all the `scanner = new Scanner(...)` stuff only once.

#### Extract common logic to helper methods

The two `insert` methods in `RadixTreeNode` are almost identical.
Don't copy-paste code. Extract common logic to a private helper method.

#### Make member variables `final` when possible

Since `mRoot` is never reassigned, why not make it `final`?

#### Other practical tips

There is a simpler way to write this:

> ```
>         mChildren = new RadixTreeNode[1];
>         mChildren[0] = node;
> ```

Like this:

```
        mChildren = new RadixTreeNode[]{ node };
```

Comment: This is awesome. I will add these changes right away and I understand the better reasoning. I think I will be a better programmer because of your post. That's the most a post can ever give!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad to hear that!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a raw array to store the children you can instead use a `HashMap<Character, RadixTreeNode>`. This will better optimize the allocations that you do.

Using a map will also remove all the for loops for searching a key in a layer.

```
Map<Character, RadixTreeNode> mChildren = new HashMap<Character, RadixTreeNode>();



public void insert(char character) {

    if(mChildren.containsKey(character)) {
        return;
    }

    addChild(new RadixTreeNode(character));
}

private void addChild(RadixTreeNode node) {
    mChildren.put(node.mCharacter, node);
}
```

Also you can get the individual characters in a String by using `charAt`, no need to get the char array.

Comment: I tried the OP's code and then replaced the array with a HashMap.  Unfortunately it seems that the HashMap used even more memory than the original.  It also made the code run slower.  My test input was a list of English words (about 170k words).  Note: I ran this on a desktop computer not on an Android device.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of @JS1 I think using less memory is more important right now..

Answer (score 2):

If you really only need to "check if a specific word exists in this list", then you need no radix tree. A `HashMap` would be the fastest, a sorted `ArrayList` would also perform pretty well.

If you can stick with English (or a 8-bit charset), then you could replace `char` by `byte` and save half the memory.

If you need to save even more, then store only the indexes and/or hashcodes of the words in memory and use a `RandomAccessFile` to get the word. The memory consumption could be something like 8 * 240000 bytes, i.e., 2 MB (not exactly negligible, but your data structure must need much more). A single disk access should be pretty fast (sub-millisecond, and if you're really lucky, your file may get cached by the OS outside of your poor 16 MB).

AFAIK `Serializable` is much slower than `Parcelable`.